# Analysing CSV file on Linux command

Tags: linux, shell, csv, command

I have a CSV file with 5 columns called "in.csv":

```
2,3,4,5,6
12,11,13,4,44
```

I want to check if for each column, column(1)+column(2) == column(3) and column(4)==column(5) holds or not, using some smart Linux command.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take this as the sample input:

```
$ cat in.csv
2,3,4,5,6
12,11,13,4,44
2,3,5,8,8
2,3,5,8,9
```

This will print all lines for which *"column(1)+column(2) == column(3) and column(4)==column(5) holds"*:

```
$ awk -F, '$1+$2==$3 && $4==$5' in.csv
2,3,5,8,8
```

This will print all lines for which *"column(1)+column(2) == column(3)"* holds while ignoring columns 4 and 5:

```
$ awk -F, '$1+$2==$3' in.csv
2,3,5,8,8
2,3,5,8,9
```

This will print all lines for which *"column(1)+column(2) == column(3)"*  is false:

```
$ awk -F, '$1+$2!=$3' in.csv
2,3,4,5,6
12,11,13,4,44
```